# How do i style each li element at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, each

I am trying to style each `<li>` element at a time on click, not all at once. For each click, the first one, then on the second click, the next one and so on...

This code puts style on all li elements at once. How do I do it?

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var menu = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; menu[i]; i++) {
    $(menu).css("background", "red");
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a>sdadsa</a>

<ul>
  <li>asda</li>
  <li>sadada</li>
  <li>sada</li>
  <li>asdad</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the list item index somehow. What have you tried?

Comment: By the way, you probably shouldn't be using an anchor (link) like that. Use a button or just a structural element. Anchors are for navigation.

Comment: @isherwood i've tried adding classes and check if the li elements has class or not, but i'm sure there is an easier way...  and that didn't work anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's .css() to check the css value of specified element

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var menu = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (var i = 0; menu[i]; i++) {
    // get element of current index
    const menuElement = menu[i];

    // if the first element's background is not red.
    if ($(menuElement).css("background") !== "red") {

      // set it red.
      $(menuElement).css("background", "red");

      // escape for loop
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add a class to do the styling.

When you click your element find the first `<li>` that doesn't have that class and add it to that one.

Adding and removing classes is typically easier than modifying and undoing inline style

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $('li').not('.red-bg').first().addClass('red-bg')
});
```

```css
.red-bg {background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a>sdadsa</a>

<ul>
  <li>asda</li>
  <li>sadada</li>
  <li>sada</li>
  <li>asdad</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that points to current li element which should change background on the next click. When the anchor tag is clicked we remove the background of previous li element and change the current element's background

```
<script>
     let current = 0;
     $("a").click(function () {
         var menu = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
         let prev = current-1;
         if(prev==-1) prev = menu.length-1;
         menu[prev].style.background = "none";
         menu[current].style.backgroud = "red";
         current = (current + 1)%menu.length;
      });
</script>
```